# how to fix "guess the song game" python

Tags: python

I am trying to create this game for guessing songs however it will not allow me to have over one song even after i change the range I also would like to know how to add the code to do scores for guessing the write song.

```
import random

for x in range(0,1):
    randNum = int(random.randint(0,1))

    song = open("Songs.txt", "r")
    songname = str(song.readlines()[randNum])
    print(songname[0])
    song.close()

    artist = open("Artists.txt", "r")
    artistname = artist.readlines()[randNum]
    print(artistname[0])
    artist.close()
    y = 0

    songGuess = input("What is the song called?")
    while(y<=2):
        if songGuess == songname:
            print("Answer correct!")
            break
        else:
            y = y + 1
            songguess = input("Incorrect! Try again:")

        if y == 2:
            print("GAME OVER")
            break
```

Comment: You are using incorrect arguments for `range` and `random.randint` @HAARISA

Answer (score 0):

- You need to change your `random.randint` range to `random.randint(0,len(song.readlines())-1)`, so that you are chosing a random index from all listed songs,and do the same thing with artists.
- A better approach is to choose a random element from the list using `random.choice` .
- Your for range `range(0,1)` will cause your loop to run just once, update the range accordingly
- You can use `with` keyword to automatically close the file instead of explicitly closing it.

So according to above changes, the fixed code might look like

```
import random

num_attempts = 10
#Run loop for num_attempts times
for x in range(0, num_attempts):

    songname = ''
    artistname = ''
    #Use with to open file
    with open('Songs.txt') as song:
        #Read all songs into a list
        songs = song.readlines()
        #Choose a random song
        songname = random.choice(songs)
        print(songname)

    with open('Artists.txt') as artist:
        # Read all artists into a list
        artists = artist.readlines()
        # Choose a random artist
        artistname = random.choice(artists)
        print(artistname)

    y = 0

    #Play your game
    songGuess = input("What is the song called?")
    while(y<=2):
        if songGuess == songname:
            print("Answer correct!")
            break
        else:
            y = y + 1
            songguess = input("Incorrect! Try again:")

        if y == 2:
            print("GAME OVER")
            break
```